# Refresh data in server explorer after remove row in context

Tags: c#, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

i have project with local database:

[image]

and first of all initial values in table:

```
Id, Name
1,  aa
2,  bb
3,  cc
```

and now i have connect by ADO.NET Enityt Data Model, names *"Database1Entities"*, look:

```
public partial class Database1Entities : DbContext
{
    public Database1Entities()
        : base("name=Database1Entities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }
```

all is ok for reading this file:

```
var context = new Database1Entities();
var products = context.Products;

products.ToList().ForEach(p=> Console.WriteLine(p.Id + " " + p.Name));
```

Return initial values, but when i remove first `(1,aa)`:

```
        var removed_prod = products.First();
        context.Products.Remove(removed_prod);
        context.SaveChanges();
```

and give repeat query:

```
products.ToList().ForEach(p=> Console.WriteLine(p.Id + " " + p.Name));
```

then result looks like:

```
2,bb
3,cc
```

Now all's Ok, when I debug again - only with code:

```
 var context = new Database1Entities();
 var products = context.Products;
 products.ToList().ForEach(p=> Console.WriteLine(p.Id + " " + p.Name))
```

then output's same:

```
2,bb
3,cc
```

but when i would to view result in `Database1.sdf -> Tables-> Products -> (PM) Show Table Data`, then i can't understand - why it's not refresh and is initial values with 3 rows. I refreshed all files, connection, REBUILD project - not results :(. It's any way to get real data in this view?
It's look:
[image]

Comment: Does the first row return to products in future run-throughs? If not, you may not be looking at the right database. It's possible VS is creating a new database and using that instead of the one you have connected.

Comment: only way to view this result's create new connection and then view this data?

Comment: If you have more than one file `(Database1.sdf)` in your project folder, the one you are using might not be the correct one. So you'd connect to the other one to see if it has the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Check for the **Connection string** in **Web.Config**.

Make sure the Datasource is same as the server you are looking in.

```
 <add name="DataContext" connectionString="Data Source=myserver.com;Initial Catalog=MyDataBase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Password=password"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```